# Unable to increase Max Application Master Resources

Tags: docker, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using `uhopper/hadoop` docker image to create yarn cluster. I have 3 nodes with 64GB RAM per node. I have added configuration. I have given 32GB 
to yarn. So total cluster memory is 96GB.

```
 -    name: YARN_CONF_yarn_scheduler_minimum___allocation___mb
      value: "2048"
    - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_scheduler_maximum___allocation___mb
      value: "16384"
    - name:  MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_framework_name
      value: "yarn" 
    - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_memory_mb
      value: "8192"
    - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_memory_mb
      value: "8192"
    - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_java_opts
      value: "-Xmx8192m"
    - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_java_opts
      value: "-Xmx8192m"
    - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_resource_memory___mb
      value: "32768"
```

Max Application Master Resources  is 10240 MB. I ran 5 spark jobs with each 3 GB driver memory, 2 jobs never came in RUNNING state due 10240MB.  I am unable to fully utilize my hardware.

[image]

How I can increase the Max Application Master Resources memory ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I hope, i found an answer, if you change `yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent` then *Max Application Master Resources* will change. Here's a documentation - *[Setting Application Limits](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.3/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/setting_application_limits.html)* from *docs.hortonworks.com*

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I have given yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=0.2 but still same Master Resources is 10240 MB

Comment: Hi, i've been trying to solve your problem, and i've found that the yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent has a default value, it's 0.2 but [apache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html) i read that the default value is 0.1 or 10%, also i'd been trying to setup my own cluster to check out it, but my laptop doesn't play well, sorry :( I hope this's going to work, you need to change your value say 0.3 at least let me know if it so :)

Answer (score 1):

To change the Maximum Application Master resources, you have to change the percentage of `yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent` , which is by default 0.2 which means 20% of the memory allocated to Yarn.

If I am not wrong, the total memory given to YARN is 10240 MB(10GB), and if the maximum percentage Application master can use is 20% then it makes the memory allocated to AM 2GB.

Now, if you want to allocate more memory to your application-master then simply increase the percentage. But it is recommended that your AM percentage should not be more than 0.5. Hope it makes it clear now.